# Killing all entities except players and armor stands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to kill every entity except players and armor stands? I've tried with

```
/kill @e[type=!Player,!ArmorStand]
```

and

```
/kill @e[type=!Player;!ArmorStand]
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `/kill @e` command because I don't regularly play in 1.8, but try `/kill @e[type!= Player, ArmorStand]`

Comment: @ModDL - not a duplicate. Yeah that's close, but it's `@e[type!=Player,type!=ArmorStand]`, I believe

Comment: Same thing, just replace the item with armor stand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run these commands first:

```
/scoreboard objectives add blackList dummy
```

Run these on a clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @e blackList 1
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Player] blackList 0
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] blackList 0
```

Lastly kill all entities that don't have a blackList score of 0:

```
/kill @e[score_blackList_min=1]
```

(edited 5/26/19 for Minecraft 1.14.1)

Comment: Since `selectMe` scoreboard objective didn't exist, I replaced it with `blacklist` and it worked like a charm :D
Thank you very much ;)

Comment: oops, made a mistake there

Comment: There should be no spaces between score_blacklist_min[SPACE]=[SPACE]1, that gives the error: The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format

Comment: @Maximuym please add the content of your edit as a new answer.