# How do I add a radius syntax to gamerule commands in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how to add a radius to:`/gamerule doMobspawning` false.
I've tried doing it like this: `/gamerule doMobspawning[r=200]` false, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As far as I know `/gamerule`s apply globally (all dimensions for the current world.

Answer (score 3):

You unfortunately can't set gamerules to a specific area- they are global and apply to every part of your world.

What you want to do is to set up a command block loop and run this command:

> /kill @e[r=20,type=!Player]

20 is the radius.

But it will kill friendly mobs/horses too. Do this to avoid that:
Run this in chat once:

> /scoreboard objectives add blackList dummy

then make a redstone clock and add as much as (but must be enough to hold them all, so you need 14) command blocks you want to it, put one line on every command block:

```
/scoreboard players set @e blackList 1

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Player] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=EntityHorse] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Villager] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Bat] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Cow] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Pig] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Rabbit] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Villager] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Chicken] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Squid] blackList 0

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Sheep] blackList 0

/kill @e[score_blackList_min = 1, r = 20]
```

Thanks to @user3878893 for providing the simpler answer.
Thanks to @ModDL [for covering the long answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204111/killing-all-entities-except-players-and-armor-stands/204163#204163)

Comment: recommended way to not kill the player is `/kill @e[r=20,type=!Player]`

Comment: @ThatGuy please Click to the green arrow icon on the left side of this question if this helped as you stated. user3878893 thanks!

Comment: Using `kill @e[type=!Player]`, even restricted to a certain area is a Bad Idea™.  You're not just killing hostile mobs, you're also killing neutral and friendly mobs, so eventually, someone's horse is going to get killed.  You don't want that.  Also, item frames, armor stands, boats, minecarts, and many more things aren't allowed in the area.

Comment: @MBraedley I sent an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  There are other things that you can do at a more localized level, but `/gamerule`s are global and effect the entire world.

But if preventing mob spawning in a particular area is what you want, you can set up a `kill` command on a fast (preferably 20Hz) clock.  For instance, you would use the command `kill @e[0,64,0,200,type=Zombie]` to continuously kill any zombie that spawns or wanders into the area that's within 200 blocks of [0,0].